# Mesh in Rendered View looks dark compared to other parts of mesh because of an extruded part I made and now I don't know how to fix it

Tags: mesh, shaders, normals

So I extruded to slivers of the body mesh and now the middle faces are weird. here is a picture included. Wondering if its the normals?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals with Shift-N?

Comment: I have and its not the normals